# ' List[ Conditional statement ] ' What is this code supposed to do

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Please  explain the statement **X[y==yi]** (after the for loop).

Code:

```
    :

    for i, yi in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        Xi = X[y==yi]
        print(Xi)
        plt.scatter(Xi[:,0], Xi[:,1], color=colors[i], marker=markers[i], label=yi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the conditional statement will evaluate to `True` or `False`.

`list[True]` works the same as `list[1]` and `list[False]` works the same as `list[0]`

```
>>> l = [0, 1]
>>> l[False]
0
>>> l[True]
1
```